# Node request blocks all outgoing requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-request

My gateway service (node 0.10 + request 2.70.0) handles dozens of requests per second . For each income request it sends request to other service (Php 5.5). Every couple of days the gateway stop sending requests to Php.

```
var request = require("request");
app.use(function(req, res,next){
    logger.info("start sending");
    request[req.method.toLocaleLowerCase()](options, function(error, response, body){
        if(!error){
            logger.info("send successfuly");
            next(response, body);
        }
        else{
            logger.error(error);
            next(error);
        }
    });
});
```

For each request all the success logs are written. But when the error happening, only the 'start send' log is written. Restart Node fix the error. I can't see the error in my logs.

Comment: does the nodejs script just halts and won't process any requests send to it ? you might consider adding some health checking to ensure everything is running as it supposed to run.

Comment: The nodejs script doesnt halts. It process new requests but, for all new requests, it prints only "start sending" logs and never return the response to client. I have heath checks.

Comment: I see you use the the request as middleware, it's possible that it launches the request but `next` is never executed or timeouts or called too many times by spamming requests, try setting `DEBUG=*` assuming that debug is used in this http server (I assume you use Express) to see what is happening.